# Django template span relationships?

Tags: python, django, templates, filter, tags

In django, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships, span relationships provide an easy way in django to do a JOIN.  Is there a way in the template to do this (using template tags)?

Comment: You'll need to give an example of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do that, I think, because when you write a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) you can import models and run queries on them just as you can anywhere else. But it violates the separation of business logic and presentation that Django's model-view-controller (or model-view-template) design works hard to preserve. Why not do your query in a view and pass the results to a template via the template's context?

If you are asking whether Django comes with a pre-built way to do this, the answer is no. The people who created Django want you to run queries in your views.